# Google sheets get empty cells next to each other

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, trim, flatten, google-query-language

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hCG6jjGSGWMn5kBkDfcoTJkZ2eCC5SRvHWMFTBp_6OE/edit?usp=sharing

I want to return "Yes" or "No" results in column N when there are empty cells next to each other in the range B:M

And column O counts the number of times there are empty cells next to each other.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in O2:

```
=INDEX(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(TRIM(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:M5="", "×", "¤")),,9^9)), 
 "¤")), "× ×"), 1, )),,9^9)), " ", )))
```

[image]

---

use in N2:

```
=INDEX(IF(O2:O=0, "No", "Yes"))
```